# Quand dit-on « à l'intention de » ou « à l'attention de » ?

Tags: expressions, sens, choix-de-mot

Je ne sais jamais dans quel contexte utiliser quelle expression, et je finis toujours par en choisir une au hasard. Ce qui est presque amusant c'est que personne ne s'en étonne, et les quelques fois où j'ai posé la question j'ai toujours eu droit à un « euh… j'avais jamais réfléchi à ça ».

Google ne m'a pas beaucoup aidé pour le coup, les résultats sont assez contradictoires ou peu fiables. J'aimerais par exemple dire « J'ai envoyé ce colis à l'{in,at}tention de Mr. X », mais je trouve les deux possibilités rien que dans la première page Google…

J'aimerais enfin démystifier cette histoire pour ne plus avoir à faire de périphrases pour éviter de dire ça !

Comment: En tant que français, je suis heureux que tu aies posé cette question, parce que j'aurais été incapable d'y répondre. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) donne pour

- à l'attention : « Remarque. Dans la langue administrative, *à l'attention de…* formule utilisée pour désigner, parmi le personnel d'une administration, le destinataire d'une note, d'une lettre, etc. »
- à l'intention : « À l'adresse de. *Il y eut encore çà et là deux ou trois épithètes malsonnantes à l'intention des Allemands* (Ambrière, Grandes vacances, 1946, p. 252). *Frédie, se touchant le nez du bout de l'index, fit à mon intention le signal de détresse* (H. Bazin, Vipère, 1948, p. 35). »

Pour moi, la seule formule à employer sur l'enveloppe est « à l'attention » qui désigne la personne *a priori* la plus propice à traiter un courrier rédigé *à l'intention* d'une entité.  Si le destinataire est une personne, on adresse le courrier à cette personne (éventuellement « aux bons soins » de chez qui elle se trouve).

Answer (score 5):

Les deux expressions existent, comme vous avez pu le constater. Elles ont une signification différente, mais elles sont souvent confondues.

L'expression que vous voulez est *à l'attention de*. Le colis ou la lettre demande l'attention du destinataire.

L'expression *à l'intention de* s'utilise dans le sens de *créé spécialement pour*, par exemple « Un ouvrage à l'intention des élèves de quatrième année. »

Comment: Je ne vois toujours pas très clairement la distinction, un colis par exemple est aussi "créé spécialement pour" quelqu'un, et demande son attention aussi, non?

Comment: Il n'y a pas toujours d'explication claire. "à l'attention de" tient de la formule administrative (au même titre que le récipiendaire d'une lettre est donné avec "à" et non "pour"). Toutefois, je n'emploierais cette expression nulle part ailleurs que dans le contexte d'un courrier, fax etc., précisément parce que c'est une expression figée.

Comment: @linker ici on attire *l'attention* du porteur et du destinataire sur un colis en mouvement, alors que l'expéditeur à eu *l'intention* (il s'est proposé un certain but) d'envoyer un colis.

Comment: Et ici que signifie la phrase `« Un ouvrage à l'intention des élèves de quatrième année. »` ?

Comment: @MarioJohnathan Ça signifie que le livre a été conçu pour être utilisé par des élèves de quatrième. Le bouquin contient des sujets appropriés au niveau de ces enfants et serait vraisemblablement trop difficile pour des enfants plus jeunes et trop facile pour des enfants plus vieux.

Comment: Merci! Là c'est beaucoup plus clair :)

Answer (score 1):

une **Intention** désigne le désir que l'on a, à réaliser un projet ou une action. Ex: j'ai '' L'Intention'' de me coucher tôt ce soir.
Une ''Attention'' définit la façon soignée de réaliser une action, soit par la rendre agréable, soit pour la rendre sans danger.

Answer (score 0):

J'ajoute un petit "truc" pour ne pas confondre les deux: on adresse un courrier "à l'*attention* de quelqu'un" parce que l'on veut attirer son *attention* sur une chose. On demande alors au destinataire de se concentrer sur un sujet particulier. De même que l'on écoutera avec "attention". L'intention, au contraire, vient de l'expéditeur: son but est d'attirer l'attention.
Mais il est vrai que la confusion est assez répandu je pense, notamment parce que les deux mots la même racine étymologique latine: *tendere* mais avec un préfixe différent.